# Linking user input to a variable in a list

Tags: python, list, variables, input, flowchart

I got the task of creating code from a flow chart as follows.

You can see what it's asking me to do and as such, I think the method to doing this would be to assign the three languages to a separate variable each and then to assign `"Welcome to ..."` to its own variable as well.

However, I'm having problems with having the user input a link to one of the variables to print whatever is in that variable. Hopefully that makes sense, I'm new to this community and coding in general so I apologise for my issues. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: So do you need to code this flowchart? If so, what language?

Comment: Yes indeed, I need to code it in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, we don't normally write code, but here you go:

```
# Get user's selected language
userLanguage = input("What is your language? (English/French/Mandarin) ") # Ask the user the question

# Compare languages
if userLanguage.lower() == "english": # If the user entered "english", forced to lower-case by .lower()
    print("Hello")
elif userLanguage.lower() == "french": # If the user entered "french"
    print("Bonjour")
elif userLanguage.lower() == "mandarin": # If the user entered "madarin"
    print("Ni Hao")
else: # The entered language was something else
    print("Sorry, but I don't speak that")

# Welcome the user
print("Welcome to ...")
```

Adjust it to how you specifically need it, but there is a Python version of the flowchart.

Comment: Ohh thanks for writing out the code specifically, I was just looking for some headway in a few functions I could use rather than the entire code but I will accept this without hesitation. Thanks it helps a lot!

Comment: @jackrussel83 There is no need to write functions for this example, as there is no code to be "reused". For this, functions will only make it messy. But if you are doing a task for school or something where you specifically need functions, I can add them in.

Comment: Ahh I see, for now I was just using this task a way of teaching myself python. I'm still unaware of a lot of the functions and layouts of python code and assumed it would use a function. Thanks again for your insight, I'm just analysing your code and working out how it works the way it does!

Comment: @jackrussel83 If you have trouble understanding the code, [see this image](https://imgur.com/a/5ovYV2S) where I added comments and clearly laid it out.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, that has cleared up the majority of the questions I had about it. I do apologise for dragging this on but does the 'elif' piece of code have a limited number of uses or can I use that as much as I like(within reason of course).

Comment: I'm completely fine answering questions :).  `if` blocks have three "parts" I guess you could call them. You have `if`, `elif` (think of as "otherwise, if:"), and `else` (think of as "otherwise, do:"). `if` statements can only start, but you can have unlimited `elif`s in a row. You can only end with an `else` statement. However, `elif`s and `else`s are not required.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help its clearing a lot of things up for me! ahh okay I see so if the if statement didn't have as many arguments to go through I could just use 'If' and then 'else'?

Comment: @jackrussel83 The `if` statement will be evaluated. This will either be `true` or `false`. If it is `true`, the code block within the `if` is run. If it is `false`, the code goes to the next part, which in this case, is an `elif`. This works in the same way.

Comment: @jackrussel83 And yes if you didn't need to check for `French` or `Mandarin` you could just use an `if` and an `else` on its own.

Comment: Ahh I see, that clears up the last of my questions then, thank you once again you've been a massive help!